# Using PDFSharp to print: how can I suppress Adobe window?

Tags: printing, pdfsharp, adobe-reader

I have a simple C# utility that invokes PDFSharp to send a PDF file to a printer. However, it seems to behave inconsistently on a Windows 7 machine. Here's the code

```
PdfFilePrinter.AdobeReaderPath = "C:\\Program Files\\Adobe\\Reader 10.0\\Reader\\AcroRd32.exe";
PdfFilePrinter printer = new PdfFilePrinter(fileToPrint, printerName);
try
{
   printer.Print();
```

When testing I launch the utility from the command line several times in a row processing a bunch of PDF files one file at a time. During some of these runs, a small Adobe window pops up. I don't have a link to what it looks like but it's a window with standard Adobe Reader X menus, a "Open a recent file" list on bottom left and "Acrobat.com services" on bottom right. Unless I manually close this window, printer.Print(); will never complete, which is a problem since I need to batch process hundreds of files at a time.

When this happens seems to be random. Sometimes it happens when the 1st test file is being processed and sometimes it's the 5th or the 7th.

How can I either ensure that this window does not appear or suppress it automatically if it does?

Answer (score 0):

Any chance your printer supports PDF natively?  If so, you could just send it directly to the printer either via LPR/RAW 9100 or through a Windows print queue: [How to send raw data to a printer](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091)